# Symfony validator with Doctrine query

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine

I'm writing a forgotten password form and, using PHP validation (as opposed to YML), I am trying to first of all check whether the e-mail address exists.

I think I'm mostly there but I can't seem to run a Doctrine query inside the validator. Here is what I have so far:

```
class EmailExistsValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    public function isValid($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE email=:email')
            ->setParameter('email', $value);
        $count = $query->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

        if ($count != 1) {
            $this->setMessage($constraint->message);

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I get "undefined property - container".

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/11/symfony2-creating-a-validator-with-dependencies-make-it-a-service/

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't show how to get a Doctrine query in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the doctrine service to the validator like this:

```
protected $doctrine;

    public function __construct($doctrine) {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }
```

and than in your services.yml:

```
my_service.my_constraint:
        class: MyCompany\MyBundleBundle\Validator\Constraints\MyValidator
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine'
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: my_name }
```

and then you can do in your validator like: $this->doctrine->getRepository('...');

Comment: I've added the code and edited DependencyInjection/Configuration.php, but now I'm getting 'There is no extension able to load the configuration...'. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you give me the complete error? Because I want to know which extension he can't load.

Comment: Why did you edit DependencyInjection/Configuration.php? Because if you place the code in your services.yml it should be loaded already.

Comment: I've removed it but I've got a similar problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29489/discussion-between-james-hadley-and-noscope)